# Google Cloud Speech - Last Names from Speech Context Phrases Lowercased

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm passing in a list of names to the Google Cloud Speech API like this:

`speech_contexts: [{ phrases: [ "Bob Smith" ] }]`

Google correctly identifies the names (like "Bob Smith") and inserts them into the text. However, they all appear in the transcription with the last name lowercased: "Bob smith". Why isn't the name appearing in the transcription in the format it was passed into the API ?

Answer (score 0):

The **phrase hints** parameter is used by Speech API to perform and boost the recognizing and transcribing tasks, improving the probability that such words or phrases will be recognized; However, it can't guarantee that the text will match exactly.

I think you should try by sending these words separately in order to validate if the service can perform the transcription as specified in the [prase hints](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#phrase-hints) as well as implement the [maxAlternatives](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#selecting_alternatives) property that will retrieve multiple alternative results that you can filter based on the confidence value.

In case none of these options are helpful, you can use the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) tool to raise and/or track a Speech API feature request in order to improve this service functionality.